# Shortcode for Visual Composer Grid fails turning string to integer

Tags: php, shortcode

I am working in a shortcode for visual composer grid. I want to show the list of terms of a taxonomy (portfolio_tag) associated to a custom post type (portfolio).
The shortcode gets the ID from the post correctly, but it is a string, not a number. When I try to use (int) or (intval) to change it to an integer it returns 0. So wp_get_post_terms is not working.

```
add_shortcode( 'proyectotag', 'ona_proyectotag' );
function ona_proyectotag($atts) {

// Attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'id' => '{{ post_data:ID }}',
        ), $atts )
    );
$tags="";
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($id, 'portfolio_tag');
foreach($term_list as $term_single) {
    $tags.= $term_single->slug; 
}
   return $tags;


}
```

What can I do? I don't understand what is happening! Could anybody help me? I feel like I have tried almost everything

Comment: Which value do you see in the post ID string?

Comment: If I do var_dump it returns: 

`string(18) "94"`

If I do `$id=(int)$id`it returns `int(0)

Comment: That is, well, impossible? Let me check it.

Comment: I wish it was impossible! Have you checked it? Do you need more information?

Answer (score -1):

```
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'product_features', array("fields" => "all"));
foreach($term_list as $term_single) {
    echo $term_single->slug; 
    //do something here
}
```

Comment: I can use $post->ID in shortcodes, but I don't know why it is not possible with shortcodes for a Visual Composer posts grid. It doesn't work

Comment: Please **always** explain **why** an answer is helpful. Just code is not enough. Also: Please care about your Markup, as this one was quite messed up. In case you copied that code from somewhere, please state the original source and look up if you are even allowed to copy that. Thanks.